# Can somebody explain me syntax of HTML SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am learning about HTML SVG.

I got following code snippets from online:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <defs>
                <pattern id="smallGrid" width="8" height="8" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                  <!-- Starts (8, 0) with a line to position (0,0) then frm there -->
                  <path d="M 8 0 L 0 0 0 8" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="0.5"/>
                </pattern>
                <pattern id="grid" width="80" height="80" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                  <rect width="80" height="80" fill="url(#smallGrid)"/>
                  <path d="M 80 0 L 0 0 0 80" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="1"/>
                </pattern>
              </defs>
              <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grid)" />
            </svg>
```

But it is not clear to me how things are working in this code, mostly the code fragments:

is unclear to me.

How should I interpret d="M 8 0 L 0 0 0 8"? What are the last two digits for?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#Path_commands

Comment: This is a matter of "finding a tutorial on SVG, or looking up the documentation for the `<path>` element". As something that you can answer for yourself with a simple google and reading, this is not a question for Stackoverflow.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

M is for "Move To", L is for "Line To".

Comment: Thanks. I was not sure where to look for.

Comment: L is line to 0  0, it is clear. but after that there are two more coordinates 0 8. What are they for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last 2 digits are an implicit LineTo command.

So `M 8 0 L 0 0 0 8` means:

- Move To 8, 0
- Line To 0, 0
- Line To 0, 8